# How to recognise gesture in superview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a view (parent) and a subview (child). The child is a UIControl, responding to UIControlEventTouchDownInside, the parent has a swipe recogniser. I would like to catch swipes even if they start in the child.

Question: how can I recognise the swipe before the tap? Is there any way to tell iphone that gestures in the parent come before gestures in the child?

Thanks for your help!

**Edit**
I just changed the child to be a UIControl (instead of using a tap recogniser). I'm not sure this matters much to the answer to this question but I thought I'd mention it anyway.

**Edit 2**

In response to the two answers I have added the tap recogniser to the child again and tried to delay (and fail) the tap recognition so that I can swipe across the big view (parent) containing the child. No luck so far.

**Edit 3**

I would really like to keep the child a UIControl and use UITouchDownInside rather than a tap recogniser because I want to use the **down** event rather than the **up** event.

**Edit 4**

Now the swipe gets detected but in the child, none of the following gets detected:
 UIControlEventTouchDragOutside, UIControlEventTouchDragExit , UIControlEventTouchCancel 
and I need at least one of these to detect when the user doesn't actually mean to tap on the child : /

Comment: you mean child is responding to UIControlEventTouchUpInside right?

Comment: @Shreesh: no, UIControlEventTouchDownInside, otherwise there is no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `- (void)requireGestureRecognizerToFail:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer` in UIGestureRecognizer. To tap, the swipe gesture has to fail.

Comment: thanks for helping me! I tried that (I want it the other way around: to swipe, tap has to fail) but it doesn't seem to work. Have you done this? Or do you *think* it works?

Comment: Just a sec, I’ll upload a simple sample somewhere. Hang on! :D

Comment: but I can't use two gesture recognisers anyway, I need the child to be a UIControl because I need to answer to the touch down event, not the touch up as the tap gesture recogniser does. I've been experimenting a bit and as it seems the swipe does get recognised sometimes (1 in 10). I wonder what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I made one short example at http://db.tt/169y2YC , using a UILongPressGestureRecognizer with a low value for minimumPressDuration. I hope it isn’t for a realtime game :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [swipeGesture delaysTouchesBegan] message to delay the touch events being delivered to the child control.

Comment: thanks for helping me. I tried [tapRecogniser setDelaysTouchesBegan:YES]; but the swipe is still not recognised.